# Referer между серверами

Tags: apache, nginx, unix, http

Как можно отследить переход с одного сервера на другой?

На стороне браузера между сайтами и внутри сайта я могу легко это определить благодаря HTTP REFERER, а вот между серверами без браузера возможно ли такое сделать?

Имеется два сервера. В случае, если на второй сервер зашли напрямую, то он выдаст localhost, т.е. не будет доступен для посещения/просмотра/пинга и прочего. Если на второй сервер попали через первый сервер, то сервер выдаст нужную информацию.

Answer (score 1):

«попали через первый сервер» — вероятно, подразумевается http-проксирование.

1. *nginx*:

   в конфигурации nginx-а [можно разрешить](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) обращения только с ip-адреса первого сервера:

   ```
   server {
     allow ip-адрес-первого-сервера;
     deny all;
     ...
   }
   ```
2. *apache версии ниже 2.4*:

   в конфигурации можно использовать директивы [allow](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) и [deny](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#deny):

   ```
   <directory ...>
     order deny,allow
     deny from all
     allow from ip-адрес-первого-сервера
   </directory>
   ```
3. *apache версии 2.4 и выше*:

   в конфигурации *apache версии 2.4 и выше* можно использовать директиву [require](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require):

   ```
   <directory ...>
     require ip ip-адрес-первого-сервера
   </directory>
   ```

   директивы allow/deny от предыдущих версий тоже можно использовать, но нельзя их смешивать с директивой require.

> для пинга

а вот это уже совсем другая история, не имеющая отношения к http-серверам.